# How to set cxx as plugin in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Below is my sonar-project.properties file. I used cppcheck externally and stored the results at csci00/cppcheck-csci00.xml which I am using as a cxx report path. However , when I run Sonar Runner it doesn't use the cxx plugin , it uses the deprecated C plugin. How do I make it use the cxx plugin ?

Also do I leave sonar.language blank to make it multi language ?

```
# required metadata
sonar.c.cppcheck.path=/home/my-proj/QTP/bin/cppcheck_wrap.sh
sonar.c.cppcheck.timeout=60000000
sonar.preview.readTimeout=60000000
sonar.projectKey=my-proj.Clouds.S6
sonar.projectName=my-proj Clouds S6
sonar.projectVersion=66
sonar.projectDescription=my-proj Clouds S6
# Set modules IDs
sonar.modules=ASC00csci00.sonar.projectBaseDir=ASC00
sonar.language=c

# Additional parameters
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources=.c,.cpp,.C
sonar.cxx.suffixes.headers=.h,.H
sonar.verbose=true

sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=csci00/cppcheck-csci00.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'sonar.language=c' by 'sonar.language=cpp'

Answer (score 0):

1. remove all plugins that are c++/c related from your extensions/plugins folder in your sonar installation
2. get latest version of the cxx plugin from github and install it in the extensions/plugins folder in your sonar installation
3. restart your server
4. remove all sonar.c. and sonar.language=c properties from your properties file
5. run a new analysis

it should now be using the sonar cxx plugin